# File size limit of Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm creating an application (.NET MVC) where users can upload files through browser to Azure Blob Storage. The files that will be uploaded is 5-10gb. Is this possible? What is the maximum file size to be able to upload to Azure Blob Storage?

Answer (score 4):

From Microsoft Documentation: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs#:~:text=Blobs%20in%20the%20Azure%20storage,maximum%20size%20of%202%20GB.)

> About Block Blobs
>
> Block blobs let you upload large blobs efficiently. Block blobs are comprised of blocks, each of which is identified by a block ID. You create or modify a block blob by writing a set of blocks and committing them by their block IDs. Each block can be a different size, up to a maximum of 100 MB (4 MB for requests using REST versions before 2016-05-31), and a block blob can include up to 50,000 blocks. The maximum size of a block blob is therefore slightly more than 4.75 TB (100 MB X 50,000 blocks). For REST versions before 2016-05-31, the maximum size of a block blob is a little more than 195 GB (4 MB X 50,000 blocks). If you are writing a block blob that is no more than 256 MB (64 MB for requests using REST versions before 2016-05-31) in size, you can upload it in its entirety with a single write operation; see Put Blob.